# A creative attack - how would you rule

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

This is a question concerning D&D 5th edition about a creative magic attack (at least it seems creative to me as a newbie)...

A low level wizard has filled a sack with 4 flasks of oil and uses mage hand  to carry the sack toward (and above) a previously cast flaming sphere - and then she  has the  hand drop the sack....

Would you let the character pull this off or not?

Comment: Hi Dave, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. See our [tour] for how we work here. Please specify the game & edition for questions; there's literally thousands of RPGs. Since you name yourself a "DM" it sounds like you're playing D&D, but it has many incompatible editions. Also, please check out the *questions to avoid asking* section of our [help/dont-ask]: this is a survey of personal opinions or a discussion starter, not a solveable problem with a correct or best answer, so we can't facilitate it in our Q&A format. You could instead [ask a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449).

Comment: As @doppelgreener notes, in its current form this question is a survey of opinions. However, it is possible to reword this question to ask if the rules prohibit such an interaction. Such a question is not opinionated and could generate a yes or no answer. You could use that answer to make an informed decision yourself about whether or not to allow such an action.

Comment: Related: [Can Mage Hand pour out a vial of acid?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77721)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. As written this is just a poll of the site membership, [a type of question we don't accept](//rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This would need to be rephrased to be asking for us to solve a specific problem (e.g., “how much damage would it do, if any?”), to be answerable in our Q&A site format. If you do actually want to poll DMs' opinions though, you may want a [discussion forum instead](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449).

Comment: Should we edit this to be something like *"what do the rules say about how this should be handled, and do they allow for it?"*?

Comment: @doppelgreener I've been tempted a couple of times, but when I started, I noticed that I can't be sure that's actually what they're stuck on, so I cancelled the edit. It's *almost* clear enough, but not quite there, so I think we need the asker to handle the clarification. It could be how much damage, it could be “is this creative witchcraft allowed??!?”, it could be “can Mage Hand do that”, it could be how the action economy of it works. Could be all kinds of things. My suspicion is that it's “what is this outside-the-box sorcery?!?”, but I can't be sure (and that would be OT anyway).

Answer (score 10):

**Should the player be allowed to "pull off" this maneuver?**

**Yes!** There's nothing in the description of *mage hand* that would rule this out, as long as the sack of oil flasks weighs less than ten pounds, and it doesn't move more than 30 feet from the caster.

A more important question is probably: **What happens?**

Here's the relevant text from the PHB about oil flasks (p. 152):

> You can also pour a flask of oil on the ground to cover a 5-foot-square area, provided that the surface is level. If lit, the oil burns for 2 rounds and deals 5 fire damage to any creature that enters the area or ends its turn in the area. A creature can take this damage only once per turn.

Assuming there are currently no creatures inside the *flaming sphere*, and that the *mage hand* drops the oil flasks so that they all break, then the easiest explanation is that four 5-foot-square areas (one for each flask) become covered in burning oil. This could most easily be the 10' x 10' area centered on the point inside the *flaming sphere* where the flasks were dropped.

Those squares would burn with the effects described above, for two rounds until the oil was consumed.

Note that the oil in adventurers' oil flasks is primarily lamp oil, for illumination. While it can burn quickly if spread over a large area, it's not the same as Alchemist's Fire, nor is it anything like modern gasoline or napalm. It's also not at all explosive, so dumping a bunch of it into a large fire doesn't cause any kind of cataclysmic effect, just a burning puddle that quickly goes away.